# Why is the compiler allowed to optimize out this busy waiting loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, compiler-optimization, busy-waiting

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
    std::atomic<bool> ready = false;

    std::thread threadB = std::thread([&]() {
        while (!ready) {}

        printf("Hello from B\n");
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    printf("Hello from A\n");

    ready = true;

    threadB.join();

    printf("Hello again from A\n");
}
```

This is an example from the CppCon talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6Ipn7gCOsY&ab_channel=CppCon (min 17)

The objective is to first print `Hello from A` then allow `threadB` to start. It is clear that busy waiting should be avoided because it uses a lot of CPU.

The author said that the `while (!ready) {}` loop can be optimized (by putting the value of `ready` into a register) by the compiler because the compiler sees that `threadB` never sleeps so `ready` could never be changed. But even if the thread never sleeps another thread could still change the value, right? There is no data race because `ready` is atomic. The author states that this code is UB. Can somebody explain why the compiler is allowed to do such an optimization?

Comment: I believe the speaker is incorrect, and this loop cannot be optimized away. The whole point of `std::atomic` is that it can in fact change spontaneously, and the compiler cannot assume otherwise. Removing the loop will very much change the observable behavior of the program, hence not a valid optimization.

Comment: Sleep tells that CPU is not needed for a certain amount of time, and that's it (and has no difference with logic taking the same amount of time), your loop will not get optimized out (removed) unless it's empty.

Comment: @Top-Master The loop is **not** empty - it calls `ready.load()`

Comment: I think that since there are 2 choices here ( optimize away the loop, don't optimize away the loop ) this would be a question of whether this is Unspecified Behavior, not Undefined Behavior

Comment: Best to think of atomics as preventing slicing and ordering. They are not also implicitly volatile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The author admits in one of the [comments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6Ipn7gCOsY&lc=UgxbLHxn2OCAgGJJ1D94AaABAg.9F-3-2SyQGl9FAhHX0qqOg) below the video that he was wrong:

> I had thought so, but it appears I was wrong; the compiler cannot hoist the atomic read out of the loop. The advice at @17:54 is still correct — you should still be very careful and beware of situations where the compiler might reorder or coalesce or eliminate atomic accesses in general — but this particular while-loop is NOT actually such a situation.
> For some (mostly theoretical) examples of how a compiler might optimize atomic access patterns, see JF Bastien's N4455 "No Sane Compiler Would Optimize Atomics" http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4455.html